# How to search the contact name with underscore in office 365?

Tags: php, api, office365

I searched contact using office 365 API I got the value. One of the scenario it displayed error message. When I used '_' symbol in request it showed response returned as HTTP error 400.

Eg:
1)https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/Contacts?$search=james kumar

No error.
I changed the name james kumar into james_kumar. Now I tried the following query.

2)https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/Contacts?$search=james_kumar
it showed as,
Array
(
    [errorNumber] => 400
    [error] => Request returned HTTP error 400
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose your term with double quotes, so like:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/Contacts?$search="james_kumar"
```